# API call with JWT token and an ID in URL

Tags: angularjs, express, jwt, http-headers, url-parameters

I am working on an angular application, where a request is being sent to the express backend. With the request, I am attaching a JWT token in the header using an auth-interceptor. The API request URL is as follows:

`http://localhost:3000/api/:userID/askQuestion`

I am sending the userId in the URL and the JWT token in the header from Frontend.

But when I am sending any request the backend is not authorizing the route. **NOTE: I am authorizing routes in the backend with the JWT token in the header.** So when I am sending the request the **auth-interceptor** is not setting the auth-token in the header for the routes which contains an ***URL parameter***.

It is working perfectly fine The routes which don't contain any *URL parameter*

Answer (score 0):

You can try add custom header using the config method to every requests.

```
 angular.module('myApp', [])
 .config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers
    .common['X-Requested-Url-Header'] = 'http://localhost:3000/api/:userID/askQuestion';
 });
```